# Laravel: Querying by id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am facing a very basic issue but just can't solve.

Two tables: `car_models` and `gear_type`. Structured like this:

[image: Model table]

[image: Gear table]

On the home page, I must show all models and which car with its gear description. So, I am doing:

```
$modelos = Modelo::all();
foreach ($modelos as $modelo) {
    $cambio = Cambio::where('id', '=', $modelo->cambio_id)->pluck('descricao');
}
// return $cambio;
return view('home', compact('banners', 'modelos', 'cambio'));
```

But the view shows:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined offset: 1 (View: /Users/marcellopato/Sites/primorossiseminovos/resources/views/home.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Undefined offset: 1 (0)
```

...and it should show the type of gear within the field indicated in the picture below.

[image: Should show: 5 gear, i.e.]

Comment: Hi there, could you please post the code of your view file as well please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you have foreign key `cambio_id` inside `modelos` table, your relationships in model should be :

```
class Modelo extends Model
{
    public function cambio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(‘App\Cambio’);
    }
}

class Cambio extends Model
{
    public function cambio()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(‘App\Modelo’);
    }
}
```

Then you can do :

```
$modelos = Modelo::with(‘cambio’)->get();
```

`with()` is the eager loading which gets `cambio` for each `modelo` instance.

Then you can do :

```
@foreach($modelos as $modelo)
    {{ $modelo->cambio->descricao }}
@endforeach
```

Somehow I feel your table structure may be updated and relationship could be reversed, but that depends on the business case also.

Comment: As I said, it was a pretty basic issue to solve. I´ve done it a lot of times but don´t know why I didn't this time.
Anyways, thank you @Mihir Bhende for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Define a relation between two models:

```
class Modelo extends Model
{
    public function cambio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(‘App\Cambio’);
    }
}
```

Load the relation while query the Modelo:

```
$modelos = Modelo::with(‘cambio’)->get();
```

In your view (blade) you could display the gear description as following:

```
@foreach($modelos as $modelo)
    {{ $modelo->cambio->descricao }}
@endforeach
```

You could read more about model relation here at [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Hummmm... it is getting an error that I´ve already saw:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cambios.modelo_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `cambios` where `cambios`.`modelo_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
```